# Scaling content on drag down in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I want to achieve the following behavior in Flutter.

[image: this]

Do you know if there is a built-in widget in Flutter that provides that functionality out of the box?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried with SliverAppBar, but using it I was not able to observe any scalling of the FlexibleSpaceBar. Is there something that needs to be enabled in order to make the content scale-in and out while scrolling?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Attach the code, please. It's recommended to add what you achieved so far. for more info, you can visit StackOverflow code of conduct

Comment: see [SliverPersistentHeader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html) - the docs say: *"A sliver whose size varies when the sliver is scrolled to the leading edge of the viewport."*

Comment: Thank you. I believe SliverPersistenHeader is what I need. :) Sorry, for not providing any code, but the current state of the code is I believe a mess and could be confusing and misleading, because of the I only provided the gif with the desired behavior.

Comment: all you need is to create a custom `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` class and implement its 4 simple methods

Comment: The final approach I used was Transform.scale in combination with GestureDetector - using the onVerticalDragUpdate. Some calculations were needed for the scale but finally everything worked as expected. Animation for scaling out was also used to achieve the desired scaling when the drag ends. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: no no no, you dont need any `Transform`, nor `GestureDetector` - i will add some answer in 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `CustomScrollView`:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: Delegate(),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
              border:  Border.all(
                width: 2.0,
                color:  Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
            height: constraints.biggest.height,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Drag me down (or up) in order to see (or hide) the red icon on the top',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textScaleFactor: 5.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
),
```

the "delegate" class is as follows:

```
class Delegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // print(shrinkOffset);
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 1 - shrinkOffset / maxExtent,
      child: FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.alarm, color: Colors.red,), fit: BoxFit.contain),
    );
  }
  @override double get maxExtent => 300;
  @override double get minExtent => 100;
  @override bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

now try to drag the text up and down

**EDIT**: and this is a little modification to be similar like your example:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: Delegate(),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 75),
            height: constraints.biggest.height,
            child: Text('Drag me down (or up) in order to make the red icon bigger (or smaller)',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              textScaleFactor: 5.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
),
```

and the modified delegate class:

```
class Delegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // print(shrinkOffset);
    return OverflowBox(
      maxHeight: 400,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        height: 400 - shrinkOffset,
        child:  FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.alarm, color: Colors.red,), fit: BoxFit.contain),
      ), 
    );
  }
  @override double get maxExtent => 300;
  @override double get minExtent => 1;
  @override bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It gives me good starting point. I will play with the provided code and will try to integrate it in my code. Kudos :)

Comment: most likely you need to play with delegate class

Comment: see `EDIT:` in my answer

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I was able to implement it using the SliverPersistentHeader. Thanks again.

Comment: I am thinking how did you write this big answer.

Answer (score 0):

[SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) now provides this feature out of the box using the `stretch` property:

```
SliverAppBar(
    stretch: true, // <- this
    flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background: Image.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover),
        title: Text('Hello again, SliverAppBar'),
        stretchModes: <StretchMode>[
            StretchMode.zoomBackground, // <- and this
        ],
    ),
);
```

Ref:

- [DartPad Example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b34900ccff8f7130c99f89af135a5c88)
- [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSc7qFzxHDw)